# How to get the next date when click on button in android?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

In my application i have a text view to set the current date and two buttons for next date and previous date.

When click on next button i need to set the next date to text view without opening the date picker and similarly to previous button also.

Please can any one help me.

Comment: You mean previous day and next day ?

Comment: Refer my Answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253122/get-previous-next-day-date-on-button-press-after-getting-date-from-previous-acti/37272467#37272467) . I did Exactly what is mentioned in this question. It may be helpful for others

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the `Calendar` to get the `current date`. And then if you want the `previous date` you `could use c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)` where `-1` is the number of days you want to decrement from `current date`. In your case we want the `previous date` so used `-1`.Similarly, to get the `next date` use `c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)`. You can get the number of days previous or before just by altering the integer.

**First of all to set current date to textview.**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

textview.setText(formattedDate);
```

**Then on previous button click:**

```
previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

                Log.v("PREVIOUS DATE : ", formattedDate);
                textview.setText(formattedDate);
             }
});
```

**On Next Button click:**

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

                Log.v("NEXT DATE : ", formattedDate);
                textview.setText(formattedDate);
            }
});
```

Comment: What if Date is not current date then how can we tackle this to and fro of date, kindly help ?

Comment: @SaadBilal hi, I want the same that you mentioned here, I want previous date of a particular date, but not today's date. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Shirish: Yes this is very easy, only you have to use calendar.set("any date") method to set any date and then you can use above logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
private static SimpleDateFormat  dateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd -MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

int dayShift = n; // Positive for next days, negative for previous days
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
if (dayShift  != 0) {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayShift);
}
mdate.setText(dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
Calendar mCalendar  = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
Date mDate          = mCalendar.getTime();
```

start of by initializing you calendar, add  `mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);` or substract `mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);` a day, get the current date, then format it to your needs